# update specific content rather than refresh entire page using nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I made a surviving game and I'm trying to show the score after game is over
[img-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXHEB.png)

I could have just add new router /game/score, but I would like to stay in same page and update score content only after submitting username.

this is my PUG file

```
  <form class="bottom-form" action="/travel?_put" method="post">
   <input type="text" class="input-timer" name="timer">
   <input type="text" class="input-name" name="username"  placeholder="What 
        is your name?" autocomplete="off" required>
   <button type="submit" class="input-button">         
    <span class="button-txt"> &#8594;</span>
   </button>
  </form>

.scoreboard 
        -var newScore= scores.sort((a, b) => (a.timer > b.timer ? -1 : 1))
        .rank-1 TOP 1 
        .username-1 #{newScore[0].username} 
        .score-1 #{newScore[0].timer} Sec
        .rank-2 TOP 2 
        .username-2 #{newScore[1].username}
        .score-2 #{newScore[1].timer} Sec
        .rank-3 TOP 3 
        .username-3 #{newScore[2].username}
        .score-3 #{newScore[2].timer} Sec
        .rank-4  
        .username-4 
        .score-4
```

and this is my index.js file. I use mongodb and nodejs

```
/////setting up mongodb////////// 
mongoose
  .connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false
  })
  .then(() => console.log("============DB connection successful!=========="));

/////////route////////////////////
app.get("/travel", (req, res) => {
  Score.find({}, (err, score) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render("game", { scores: score });
    }
  });
});
app.post("/travel", (req, res) => {
  const score = new Score({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    username: req.body.username,
    timer: req.body.timer,
    timestamp: new Date()
  });
  Score.create(score, err => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(score);
      res.status(204).send();
    }
  });
});
app.put("/travel", (req, res) => {
  Score.find({}, (err, score) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send("game");
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a `POST` route and make `AJAX` request from `pug`. I.e.

### index.js

```js
app.post('/api/score', (req, res) => {
     // Get params from req, and make logic ...

     // Send data to front end
     res.json({
       message: 'Score updated'
     });
});
```

### PUG

```
script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js')
script.
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bottom-form').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post({url: "/api/score", data, success: function(result){
     // Update score from here
      }});
    });
  });
```

I've used jQuery here, but you can feel free to use vanilla js, or any other lib for this.